# Schematic notation for decoupling capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, operational-amplifier

[image: circuit schematic]

I'm wondering where this capacitor should be placed. Is it a decoupling capacitor? There are two supply rails on this particular op-amp, so I'm assuming that this indicates I need to put one between each rail and ground. Any insight would be appreciated!

Edit: the data sheet can be found here http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/ca31/ca3130.pdf

Comment: It says 0.001 for 3 so that would indicate to me between pin  3 which is the positive side of the op amp and ground. Which makes some sense because you want the reference pin (3) to be non-moving usually.

Comment: Why not just draw the cap on the non-inverting input? Usually power pins are drawn where the cap is drawn now. It looks like the *(.001 FOR 3* is cut off. Whats the rest? There's no unit.. .001 uF? 1nF? Kinda small for a decoupling cap, no?

Comment: @erythraios  Could you provide more context?  Where does the schematic come from?  What's the model of the OpAmp?  If you post a link to the datasheet, that would be ideal.  To me, this doesn't look like a decoupling capacitor.  The decoupling cap is usually between supply rail and ground.  Welcome to EE.SE, by the way.

Comment: I have a very vague recollection that some early op-amps had terminals for a frequency compensation capacitor (or maybe I'm confused with offset adjustment pots).

Comment: Thanks for all the input! I've added the data sheet for the op-amp, and will add some more details shortly if necessary.

Comment: It is for a compensation cap (to prevent ringing) pins 1 & 8, see figure #1, 8A (schematic)

Comment: @placeholder that would make sense, except it seems that there is a 0.01uF decoupling capacitor in that same schematic, which matches up with the 0.01 in my original schematic. Is there any harm in adding all three (positive decoupler, negative decoupler, and compensation)? I don't see any other way of telling

Comment: For what it's worth, that's a very rare way to connect a compensation capacitor or network. More often it was a series R-C between pins 1 and 8. Kind of conflicts with the "ANY OP AMP" text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Omitting the supply rails and decoupling capacitors is a common shorthand in circuit diagrams.  It's admissible, when supply rails are not important for the discussion.

0.001 μF in the original post is not a decoupling capacitor.  It's a compensation capacitor between pins 1 and 8 of the CA3130 OpAmp.

[image]

fig.8 on p.9 in the [datasheet](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/ca31/ca3130.pdf).   Decoupling capacitors in this schematic are 0.01 μF, compensation capacitor in this schematic is 56 pF.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any easy way to explain why this is connected between the strobe and null offset pins? I'm sort of new to hardware

Comment: The consequence of using such a huge capacitor (~20x the minimum required value for unity-gain stability) is you'll end up with an extremely sluggish voltage follower. It might be justified if the amplifier was called upon to drive a cable or other capacitive load.